# GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) issue in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm getting the following error in the application logs that trying to connect to a Cassandra cluster with 6 nodes

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [DB1:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
```

I have set java heap memory to 8GB (-Xms8G -Xmx8G), wondering if 8 GB is too much?

Below is time out configuration in cassandra.yaml

```
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

range_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000

write_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
```

In the application there aren't heavy delete or update statements, so my question is what else may cause the long GC pause? the majority types of the GC pause that I can see in the log is G1 Evacuation Pause, what does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The heap size heavily depends on the amount of data that you need to process.  Usually for production workload minimum of 16Gb was recommended.  Also, G1 isn't very effective on the small heaps (less than 12Gb) - it's better to use default `ParNewGC` for such heap sizes, but you may need to tune GC to get better performance. Look into this [blog post](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/04/11/gc-tuning.html) that explains tuning of the GC.

Regarding your question on the "G1 Evacuation Pause" - look into this blog posts: [1](https://plumbr.io/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms-implementations/g1/evacuation-pause-fully-young) and [2](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/understanding-g1-gc-logs).  Here is quote from 2nd post:

> Evacuation Pause (G1 collection) in which live objects are copied from one set of regions (young OR young+old) to another set. It is a stop-the-world activity and all
> the application threads are stopped at a safepoint during this time.

For you this means that you're filling regions very fast and regions are big, so it requires significant amount of time to copy data.

Comment: Seems I need to increase Java heap size, but I'm wondering by increasing from 8 GB to 12 or 16 GB, we would have longer GC pauses, any thoughts on this?